# How to delete duplicate words within a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete duplicate words within a cell. For example, in cell A1 I have the following:

```
"BOX TIL Rank Fifth TIL Over 01"
```

I am trying to figure out a way in which excel will look into this cell and delete the second `"TIL"` so it will look like this instead:

```
"BOX TIL Rank Fifth Over 01"
```

I am trying to do this not only in one but a whole column of cells. The other issue is that some cells have longer strings for example, one might look like the one above, but another might like this:

```
"BOX TIL Seventeen TIL COMM 03"
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Will there always be at most one pair of duplicates (i.e. could "TIL" and "WHEN" both be duplicates in one cell)? Can there be more than 2 duplicates (i.e. "TIL" repeated three or more times)? Is the word always "TIL"?

Comment: Have you tried splitting the column into two columns, separating them at the first TIL and then remove the second TIL by selecting your new column and using find a replace?

Comment: Yes there are some that have two words with duplicates. Only 2 duplicates are there and the word isn't always "TIL"

Comment: I have but it did not work for me to many different variations on each cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through your cells and use the following function to remove duplicate words.

```
Public Function RemoveDuplicateWords(InputString As String) As String
    Dim InputArray() As String
    InputArray = Split(InputString, " ")

    Dim DictUnique As Object
    Set DictUnique = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim OutputString As String

    Dim Word As Variant
    For Each Word In InputArray
        If Not DictUnique.Exists(Word) Then
            DictUnique.Add Word, 1
            OutputString = OutputString & " " & Word
        End If
    Next Word

    RemoveDuplicateWords = Trim$(OutputString)
End Function
```

**How does the function work?**

- It splits the string by spaces into an array
- It uses a dictionary to check if the words are unique
- If the word is not in the dictionary yet it is added to the `OutputString`, duplicate words are not added to the `OutputString`.

**You can even use it as formula**

```
=RemoveDuplicateWords(A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this worked exactly like I wanted it to, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this short VBA macro:

```
Sub RemoveDups()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, arr
    Dim c As Collection

    For Each r In Selection
        Set c = New Collection
        arr = Split(r.Value, " ")
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            On Error Resume Next
                c.Add arr(i), CStr(arr(i))
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i

        s = ""
        For i = 1 To c.Count
            s = s & " " & c.Item(i)
        Next i
        If Left(s, 1) = " " Then s = Mid(s, 2)
        r.Value = s
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: You could reduce it to one `i` loop if you test for `Err.Number = 0` in the first loop and add it to the string directly. Should be faster than looping twice.